# Converting a textfile into a list

Tags: list, python-3.5

I have a text file which contains a series of movie titles, which looks like this once opened.

> A Nous la Liberte (1932)   About Schmidt (2002)    Absence of Malice
>   (1981)     Adam's Rib (1949)   Adaptation (2002)   The Adjuster (1991)     The
>   Adventures of Robin Hood (1938)    Affliction (1998)   The African Queen
>   (1952)

Using the code below:

```
def movie_text():
     moviefile = open("movies.txt", 'r')
     yourResult = [line.split('\n') for line in moviefile.readlines()]

movie_text()
```

I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't prints right.

If I understand it well,

```
moviefile = open("movies.txt", 'r')
lines=moviefile.readlines()
print(len(lines)) # Shows list size
for line in lines:
    print(line[:1]) # The [:1] part cuts the \n
```

The method readlines returns a list, I am not sure why your use split. I mean, if all you want is to remove the '\n', you can do it in many ways, being the one I used just one of them.

Hope it works!